# progressbar position increment in multithread

Tags: multithreading, delphi, progress-bar

I made a multiThread download application, and now I got to show the progress of each downloading Thread, like in IDM, When Data is downloaded the progressbar is notified about downloaded data, and as you know each thread position in progressBar had to begin from a specified position, now the question is:
How can I increment progressposition according to downloaded data, it is pretty simple in monothread by using IDHTTPWORK, so can I use the same method in multithread application or is there another simple method to implement?
Do I need to synchronise the instructions that increment position?

Comment: You **always** have to synchronize if you want to access VCL/FMX from a different thread context as the main thread context

Comment: If you run a `TIdHTTP` in a worker thread, you can still use its `OnWork...` events.  They will simply run in the context of the worker thread, not the UI thread, so you have to use an inter-thread syncing mechanism (`TThread.Synchronize()`, `TThread.Queue()`, `TIdSync`, `TIdNotify`, window/thread messages, etc) to update the UI in a thread-safe manner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose you have N downloads, of known size `M[i]` bytes. Before you start downloading, sum these values to get the total number of bytes to be downloaded, `M`.

While the threads are working they keep track of how many bytes have been downloaded so far, `m[i]` say. Then, at any point in time the proportion of the task that is complete is:

```
Sum(m[i]) / M
```

You can update the progress out of the main thread using a timer. Each time the timer fires, calculate the sum of the `m[i]` counts. There's no need for synchronisation here so long as the `m[i]` values are aligned. Any data races are benign.

Now, `m[i]` might not be stored in an array. You might have an array of download thread objects. And each of those objects stored all the information relating to that download object, including `m[i]`.

Alternatively you can use the same sort of synchronized updating as you do for single threaded code. Remove the timer and update from the made thread when you get new progress information. However, with a lot of threads there is a lot of synchronization and that can potentially lead to contention. The lock free approach above would be my preference. Even though it involves polling on the timer.

Comment: I'll try it and inform you about the result.

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at the subclassed MFC list controls developed in the article by Michael Dunn 15 years ago: Articles/79/Neat-Stuff-to-Do-in-List-Controls-Using-Custom-Dra on codeproject dot com.

If you implement one of them, say, CXListCtrl* pListCtrl, at thread creation time, then the progress reporting of that thread becomes as simple as making calls such as:

```
pListCtrl->SetProgress(mItem,0);
```

when it's time to start showing progress, and

```
pListCtrl->SetProgress(mItem,0, i);
```

when you're i% done.

Actually, if you just want the progress bar functionality and don't care about all that's under the hood, you could obtain and use without modification (or license issues) the class XListCtrl.cpp in the Work Queue article at Articles/3607/Work-Queue on that same site.

Comment: thanks, I'll try it, but could you give me a  link? I can't find the article.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3607/Work-Queue

and

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/79/Neat-Stuff-to-Do-in-List-Controls-Using-Custom-Dra

Comment: The problem you'll face is that you won't be able to use that MFC control (assuming there is no other half-working multilanguage framework attempting to incorporate something *foreign* into Delphi).

Comment: Oh, my bad.  I missed that she was in Delphi.  A hacked MFC control, however elegant it might be living in the MFC, would almost certainly be of no use to her.